# Первичные ключи в sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Имеется БД, в ней несколько таблиц. В каждой таблице есть колонка id. Вопрос, как сделать одним скриптом колонку id первичным ключом? Т.е. чтобы в каждой таблице был первичный ключ (id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По системным каталогам находим таблицы, у которых есть колонка `ID`, но нет первичного ключа, и генерируем для них SQL запрос на его добавление:

```
select
    N'alter table ' + quotename(s.name) + N'.' + quotename(t.name) + N'
    add constraint ' + quotename(N'PK_' + t.name) + N' primary key ([ID])
GO'
from sys.schemas s
    join sys.tables t on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id and c.name = N'ID'
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from sys.key_constraints k
        where k.parent_object_id = t.object_id and k.type = 'PK'
    )
```

Выполняем данный запрос в SSMS, в результате чего сгенерируется SQL код наподобие:

```
alter table [dbo].[TableName]
    add constraint [PK_TableName] primary key (ID)
GO
alter table [dbo].[TableName2]
    add constraint [PK_TableName2] primary key (ID)
GO
...
```

Этот код копируем в новое окно и исполняем.

Если нужно автоматическое выполнение, то, вместо ручного копирования и исполнения, оборачиваем данный запрос в курсор и выполняем с помощью `exec(@sql)` (потребуется только убрать разделитель `GO` из конкатенации).

Comment: как будет автоматическое выполнение, `alter table [ ]` что мне надо писать

Comment: таблиц много у меня

Comment: `Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "+"`  строка 2

Comment: @propro17, _"неправильный синтаксис"_ - это вы `GO` убирали? Может быть кавычку стёрли нужную. Скопировал скрипт из ответа, прогнал по тестовой базе - всё работает. Вам точно нужно автоматическое выполнение? Если это разовый скрипт, то проще всего сделать как написано в ответе. В SqlServer Management Studio выполните запрос, он сгенерирует команды. Скопируйте их все разом в буфер, откройте новое окно запросов (нажать Ctrl+N), вставьте команды из буфера и запускайте на исполнение.